# How to build a 3D model in RViz using data from a Sick LMS200?

Tags: ros, rviz, 2dlaserscan, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I have Sick LMS200 30106 (sitting on top of a servo) and it is connected to my PC via RS422 to USB. Here is what it looks like:

[image: image description]

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS indigo. I am using the sicktoolbox_wrapper package to pass the scan data to RViz (via the /scan topic). I am able to see a single scan line at a time in RViz:

[image: image description]

I am trying to create a 3D model like this gentleman: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Tpqwty4V90. In the comments he alludes to a SickLms package, but I have not been able to find it in the ROS packages in the software section. I played a bunch with all the settings in the LaserScan type in RViz, and read http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/LaserScan, and I could not figure out how to make the data appear in 3D. I also searched all over the web, but could not find any instructions on how to achieve this objective (except this - http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/roswiki/laser_pipeline(2f)Tutorials(2f)IntroductionToWorkingWithLaserScannerData.html, but it is too complex for me to understand if this is what I need to pursue).

I am new to ROS, and from what I saw online I am not the first person who is very new to ROS to seek this objective. Could you please provide some guidance on how to do this? Does a package exist for this purpose? And if not, which packages do I need to learn to achieve my objective?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272526/how-to-build-a-3d-model-in-rviz-using-data-from-a-sick-lms200?/) by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2017-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like the [laser_assembler](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler) package will do what you're looking for.

It looks like this package has two things that you'll need to set up before you can use it:

- A ROS node to publish laser scan messages. It looks like you already have this.
- A ROS node to publish the transform (ie rotation) of your laser scanner, using the TF library.

There aren't a lot of great tutorials for how to set up TF, but this seems the closest to your robot: http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher , since it shows to to do both the differential drive and the rotational joints.

If you haven't already, I'd recommend that you do the other URDF tutorials too: http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials

Once you've done those, it should be relatively easy to come back and do the laser assembler tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler/Tutorials/HowToAssembleLaserScans

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1